Bash script to generate files based on the contents of array
So I'm hacking together a bash script to generate html pages with links to video files and I have come to a stumbling block. I want to be able to add links to videos by date to minimise the number of links per page then have a index page with links to the days available and how many videos are available for that day. This is to allow easy access to video files created by a motion from a  webcam setup on a raspberrypi with lighttpd so it needs to be simple to reduce load on the pi. I would be running the bash script with cron in the early morning when there would be no videos being recorded.
I would be adding the finished script to github/gitlab and linking it back to this page if anyone is interested in doing the same
index page
01/04/2024 - 10 videos
02/04/2024 - 20 videos
etc... 

and each days page
thumbnail - time - length - download link

this is what I have been able to hack together so far which generates the thumbnails but fails to generate the html pages.
./test2.sh: line 128: 2024-03-25.html: command not found
./test2.sh: line 128: : No such file or directory

The filenames for the videos are in the format (yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss) Ignore the html code as I will be changing this when I get the rest of the code working and there are a few echo's to check the contents of arrays which would be removed from the script once I have finished testing.
#!/bin/sh

set -e

script_dir=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
cd "$script_dir" || exit

#list of directories
videos_dir="/home/allan/Documents/videos/"
thumbs_dir="/home/allan/Documents/thumbnails/"

mkdir -p "$videos_dir"
mkdir -p "$thumbs_dir"

#Declare arrays
parts=()
combine=()
args=()
uniq=()


# Loop over all video files.
for video_file in "$videos_dir"/*; do
    video_name="$(basename "${video_file}")"
    thumb_name="$(basename "${video_file%.*}.jpg")"
    thumb_file="$thumbs_dir/$thumb_name"

    # If thumnail doesn't exist for this video.
    if [ ! -e "$thumb_file" ]; then
        printf "generating thumbnail: %s\n" "$thumb_name"
        ffmpeg -loglevel error -i "$video_file" -vf "thumbnail,scale=320:240" -frames:v 1 "$thumb_file"
    fi

   parts=(${video_name//-/ })
   combine=(${parts[0]}-${parts[1]}-${parts[2]})
   args+=("$combine")

    # Generate html for each item.
    items_html="$items_html""
        <div class='grid-item-container'>
            <img class='grid-item' src='${thumb_file}' data='${video_file}'/>
            <div class='player-top-bar'>
                <span class='player-top-bar-text'>$video_name</span>
            </div>
        </div>"
done

echo "${args[@]}"
uniq=($(printf "%s\n" "${args[@]}" | sort -u)); echo  "${uniq[@]}"

for day in "${uniq[@]}"; do
# Write html page for each day with videos
echo "
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title>Video Viewer</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>
<body>
    <div style='display:grid; grid-template-columns:repeat(var(--gridsize), auto)'>
        $items_html
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const element = event.target;
        if (element.className !== 'grid-item') {
            return;
        }

        const videoPath = element.getAttribute('data');
        const videoElement = document.createElement('video');

        videoElement.className = 'grid-item'
        videoElement.setAttribute('controls', '')
        videoElement.setAttribute('autoplay', '')
        videoElement.setAttribute('data', element.src)

        const sourceElement = document.createElement('source');
        sourceElement.src = videoPath
        videoElement.appendChild(sourceElement)

        element.parentNode.replaceChild(videoElement, element);
    });
</script>

<style>
.grid-item-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
}
.grid-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.player-top-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.player-top-bar-text {
    padding: 0.05em 0.4em 0.05em 0.2em;
    color:  hsl(215deg, 40%, 90%);;
    font-size: 40%;
    background: hsl(215deg, 40%, 8%);
}

:root {
    font-size: 12vw; /* Window scale */
    --gridsize: 1;
}

/* Tablet/Dektop. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    :root {
        font-size: 4.5vh; /* Window scale. */
        --gridsize: 3;
    }
}
</style>" > "$("${day}.html")" ;
done


fails to generate the html pages. - fails how? error msg? wrong output? no output? script hangs?

please update the question with a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the issue; if the 1st for loop is 'working' then replace it with the output from typeset -p args; the 2nd 'for' loop should be cut down to just enough code to demonstrate the issue (ie, we don't need to see 76 lines of static html code) .... it looks like the 2nd 'for' loop is merely generating a set of output files where $day is used to build the file name (so consider something simple like echo abc > new_file_$day_name)

You can do this with the shell, but it is probably not the best choice for this kind of work.  I would reach for Python, myself, but there are other alternatives that would likewise make development and maintenance easier than targeting a shell script, and would probably yield a program faster than a shell script, too.

What do you think "$("${day}.html")" means?  Do you really intend to produce a file name by running a .html file as a program?

I encourage you to not echo a huge, multiline string.  It's a lot clearer to cat a heredoc, instead.

This ... $(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")") ... is a risky way to try to determine the script's installation directory.  It likely will not work as intended if the script is looked up in the path instead of directly by its name.

Why is $combine an array?

Anyway, the bug is clearly in "$("${day}.html")". That should just be "${day}.html"

@markp-fuso thanks for the reminder I have added the error message from the terminal. If I knew what in the code was causing the issue I wouldn't be posting it on a "help" platform on the internet I can post it on git and link to it instead

@JohnBollinger I know that I can use python instead and I may create a python version to learn some more python at a later date but I was looking for a quick and dirty solution to the problem (easy access to videos produced by motion). If you know what the answer to the problem is you could add an answer and maybe throw in a example of how this could be done better in python so others wouldn't waste their time  doing the same in bash.

@Barmar I don't know why $combine is an array I was learning how arrays work in bash and found a solution to get the data (dates with existing videos) the next step would be to find a way of adding the correct videos to each html file I am learning bash and hacking together something that "works" at the same time. As it seems you have a solution you could add that as an answer as apposed to adding it as a comment and include a better solution for $combine

the question has been tagged with bash but the script has a shebang of #!/bin/sh; while /bin/sh may actually refer to /bin/bash in your environment this is not guaranteed to be the case in other environments (eg, in my Ubuntu environment /bin/sh is actually /bin/dash); if your intent is to run your script under bash then consider updating the script with an explicit reference to bash in the shebang (ie, #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/env bash)

@Allan, how quick is it really when trying to do it with the shell gets you in enough trouble that you need to get third-party troubleshooting assistance?  Choosing an appropriate language for the task will make development easier and bugs less likely.  I like the shell, and I do a fair amount of shell programming, but I would have reached for Python here for a quick and clean alternative.  Your particular language repertoire might incline you in another direction, but if the shell is the best you've got for this task then you should consider expanding your expertise.

The error message mentions line 128.  Here's line 128:
</style>" > "$("${day}.html")" ;

The error message also mentions 2024-03-25.html: command not found.  In other words bash is trying to run 2024-03-25.html as a command.
This all ties back to a previous comment: What do you think "$("${day}.html")" means?
The construct $( .... ) invokes a subshell that executes whatever's between the parens.  Assuming day=2024-03-25 this means your code becomes:
$(2024-03-25.html)

Since 2024-03-25.html is likely not a valid binary, script, function or alias in your environment you get the error message.
Since the objective of this part of the script is to write 76 lines of static html code to a file there's no need to invoke a subshell just to desginate a file name.
The simple fix:
#### replace this:

</style>" > "$("${day}.html")" ;

#### with this:

</style>" > "${day}.html"

NOTE: in this case the trailing ; is superfluous
